# c# webbrowser doesn't load the url

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have a panel which displays a form which displays a webbrowser. In the UI designer I added the Url of my .html file and it worked fine.

But now I am using my application on a different system and thus the path to the .html does not exists.

So I have to do it in code and use `string sspBaseFile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`

In this function I am trying to get it to work. The form has a UI element called webbrowser1

```
private void SSP_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentTitleChanged);

        this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
        webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(sspBaseFile + "frmSSPeditor.html"));           
    }
```

Why isn't the html displayed? I verified that the .html is in the correct place, next to the binary.

Comment: What is the value of `sspBaseFile` on the machine where it works? On the machine where it doesn't work?

Comment: Either you are getting an exception, sspBaseFile is wrong, or another setting in the project is wrong..

Comment: I am still testing on my work pc. Console.WriteLine(sspBaseFile + "frmSSPeditor.html") returns the correct path